# Пробелы/табуляция в git/github комитах

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

Суть проблемы, редактирую код используя atom после этого делаю гит комит и пуш в гитхаб

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так чтобы гит не учитывал удаление пробелов и табуляций в конце строк

Comment: лучше настроить атом так, что бы о использовал подходящие символы. Смешивание пробелов и табов в одном файле ни к чему хорошему не приведет.

Answer (score 0):

В самом интерфейсе *GitHub* для просмотра изменений файлов коммита я такой опции не нашел, но в к запросу можно дописать параметр `&w=1` (по аналогии с [Code Review](https://github.blog/2018-05-01-ignore-white-space-in-code-review)), который будет игнорировать пробелы.

```
https://github.com/<YOUR_COMMIT_LINK>?diff=unified&w=1
```

В текущей реализации аналогичной опции для табуляции, вроде, нет.